# Uncaught (in promise) Type Error when trying to fetch for URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a server using Node.js and used the Express framework. Once the server was running, I went to Google Chrome and when to inspect element and went to the console, and typed - `fetch('http://localhost:7500')`. I was expecting to get the CORS error(Which I wanted) but instead got this:

```
VM267:1          GET http://localhost:7200/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

VM267:1          Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Is there any way to resolve this error?

Comment: What research and debugging have you done? If I search for ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT, I find a lot of hits talking about ad blockers, etc. Interestingly, Brave (which has built-in ad blocking) throws ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT if I try `fetch("http://localhost:80")` in the console when I'm on this page (I have a server running on port 80), but Chrome doesn't (I get an SOP error [which many will incorrectly call a CORS error]).

Comment: I do use the Brave browser. But even when using Google Chrome, I get the same error.

Comment: Perhaps you're using an ad blocker in Chrome? Again, that's what most search results point to.

Comment: It's ok, I found out the problem, I have to set an origin, Apparently, you have to specify the site URL where you request the fetch. It does not work for all sites. Anyway, thank you for helping.